# how to determine azure service bus Namespace Type

Tags: azureservicebus

Azure Service Bus has 3 types of namespaces. How to determine type of an existing namespace? I have looked into [NamespaceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.aspx) class and couldn't find anything.

**Update**: another approach is to use [Azure Management Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries). Issue with either approach is that you have to have a certificate to be deployed to Azure account, which complicates things a lot more. Feels more of a .NET client library deficiency, which hopefully could be addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to use the REST API. If you use Fiddler while using the Get-AzureSBNamespace PowerShell cmdlet, you'll see that it makes a GET request to management.core.windows.net to retrieve information about the namespace (including the namespace type). Although https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn140232.aspx appears to suggest you'll receive an empty response, you actually get a Namespace Description (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj873988.aspx) in the response.

The sample code here (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Bus-Resource-5d887203) will point you in the right direction for making these REST calls yourself.